# Page layout issues/design issues

Tags: jquery, html, css, layout, user-interface

I have a page I want to display with

- a menubar along the top border of the screen, for the entire width:
- an image aligned to the middle of the page and along the left border of the screen,
- a div box (middle-aligned text) in the center and another image (same dimensions as the first) on the right border of the screen - this is called mainBlock
- a white band with the logo in the center, along the bottom border of the screen.

How do I set up the divs and the positions so that this works? If I use absolute positioning, then it gets screwed up when the page is resized. The code I have right now is

```
<div style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;width:100%;height:45px;background-color:black;color:white;text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;display:block;line-height:45px;">
    <font size="+2">About | Sign Up | Sign In</font>
</div>

<div style="position:absolute;top:80px;left:10px;width:4em;opacity:0.8;filter:alpha(opacity=80);background-color:white">
    <img src="img/bk.png" id="bkArrow">
</div>

<div id="mainBlock" style="position:absolute;top:80px;left:35px;opacity:0.8;filter:alpha(opacity=80);background-color:white;border-style:solid;border-width:2px;border-radius:4px;vertical-align:middle;border-color:green;">
    Main area for my content
</div>

<div style="position:absolute;top:80px;right:10px;width:4em;opacity:0.8;filter:alpha(opacity=80);background-color:white" >
    <img src="img/fw.png" id="fwArrow">
</div>

<div style="position:absolute;left:0px;bottom:0px;background-color:white;width:100%;" align=center>
    <img src="img/logo.png">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ofcourse you question is not very clear , but from what i have concluded , you had to use a wrapper to bound all these div , you may try following ( resize window as well ):

```
<div id="wrapper" style="width:100%; height:100%;" >
<div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 15%;
background-color: black; color: white; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; display: block; line-height: 45px;">
<font size="+2">About | Sign Up | Sign In</font>
</div>

<div style="position: absolute; top: 15%; left: 0px; width: 10%; opacity: 0.8; filter: alpha(opacity=80); background-color: #FFFFFF; height: 75%;">
<img src="img/bk.png" id="bkArrow">
</div>

<div id="mainBlock" style="position:absolute;top:15%;left:10%; height:75%; width:80%;opacity:0.8;filter:alpha(opacity=80);background-color:white;border-style:inset;border-width:2px;border-radius:4px;vertical-align:middle;border-color:green;">
Main area for my content</div>
<div style="position: absolute; top: 15%; right: 0px; width: 10%; opacity: 0.8; filter: alpha(opacity=80); background-color: #FFFFFF; height: 75%;" >
<img src="img/fw.png" id="fwArrow"></div>

<div id="footer" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; bottom: 0px; background-color: white; width: 100%; height: 10%;" align=center>
<img src="img/logo.png"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Accepting this. Have edited the original solution slightly to get the left-side image (bk.png) aligned along with the box, but the rest of the answer was bang-on. Thanks!